# Exchange 2010 multidomain

Tags: windows, exchange

I have 1 exchange server and I am using multiple domains on it. I want to separate each domain user.

The MS Exchange and Active Directory domain is  example.com and I have added another accepted domain example.org.

When I create a user mailbox on example.com then user should only be able to login using username@example.com but my problem is that a user on example.com can also login using domain example.org i.e. user1@example.org can login using both user1@example.org and user1@example.com. when I create a mailbox using UPN suffix example.org, then the user should only be able to signin using username@example.org.

user1@example.org is still accepting mails which user sents to user1@example.com although I have removed the smtp address. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done, but you have a lot of reading ahead of you.  You're probably going to need to reinstall exchange, and setup a new active directory forest.

You don't mention what service pack you are using.  In SP1 there was the [/hosting mode](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff923272(v=exchg.141).aspx) which enabled multi tenant mode.  This was quickly depreciated [and no longer recommended](http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2011/10/13/future-of-hosting-mode.aspx).  It still exists in SP2, but is not recommended for new installs.

There are [several](http://www.msexchange.org/articles-tutorials/exchange-server-2010/management-administration/automating-multi-tenancy-exchange-server-2010-sp2-part1.html) different [guides](http://www.jaapwesselius.com/2012/04/06/building-hosted-exchange-2010-part-i/) for setting up Exchange 2010 SP2 for multiple tenants.  It's not nearly as simple as setting up regular exchange, but it can be done.

If you don't want to do ALL the work yourself, Microsoft also lists some [validated third party solutions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dn756395) that help manage exchange for multiple tenants.